# Where can I find historical data on call options for Ethereum?

Tags: ether, price

I am trying to find historical data on call option for Ethereum and Bitcoin. I've had no luck finding it. So far I've only been able to get current option prices and onwards. Does anyone know where or how I can find this data?

Answer (score 1):

You can get them on Deribit, free but only on Deribit orderbook (https://docs.deribit.com/#private-get_order_history_by_instrument)
And on Kaiko, not free but it aggregates multiple exchanges.